# Matlab Plot two loglog axis on same graph

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, loglog

I would like to know if the following type of plotting is possible in Matlab.

I think it is called a multiple loglog plot.

[image]

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html - does this work for you?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin that is unfortunately not what I am looking for, you will notice there is another set of loglog plots in the main one, however they all refer to the same plot though.

Comment: Probably you will have to code it by yourself. I doubt that there is a built-in function for that